# Attaching data to a button in a cell from a row in a table that is dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I've searched and searched through many stacks and have not been able to solve my problem:

I have a HTML table that is generated based on mustache values and is organized like so:

```
         <tbody>
          {{#Result.Rows}}
            <tr id={{deal_id}}>
              <td>{{azuqua_org_id}}</td>
              <td>{{company_name}}</td>
              <td>{{deal_title}}</td>
              <td>{{deal_value}}</td>
              <td>{{csm}}</td>
              <td>{{days_until_renewal}}</td>
              <td class="renewal">{{renewal_date}}</td>
              <td class="dealId">{{deal_id}}</td>
              <td>{{company_org_id}}</td>
              <td>{{#comments}}{{comments}} - {{Comment Last Mod}}{{/comments}}
              <a href="#commentModal" role="button" data-id="{{deal_id}}" id="cmtOpen{{deal_id}}" class="btn btn-custom btn-xs" data-toggle="modal">Comment</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          {{/Result.Rows}}
        </tbody>
```

The last column in each row is a comment box and has a small comment button inside it that shows a modal window that will allow you to add a new comment to that cell. the modal window HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="commentModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="commentBox" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">New Comment</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="deal-label"
                  <p><span type="text" class="label-sm" id="txtId"/></p>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <p>Type a new comment below:</p>
                  <textarea  id="commentBody"></textarea>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer" id="modalButtons">
                  <button class="trigger btn btn-default" type="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                  <button class="trigger btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" id="cmtSubmit">Submit</button>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my JS for the HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Document ready');
  studio.select("table-2").onPageLoadSuccess(attachKeyupHandler);
});

var attachKeyupHandler = function() {
  $("#searchBar").ready(function() {
    console.log('searchBar is ready')
    var sb = $("#searchBar");
    console.log(sb);
    sb.keyup(function(event) {
     console.log('key up on search bar');
     searchFilter();
    });
    
  $("#cmtOpen").ready(function() {
    console.log('CommentBtn is ready')
    var cmb = $("#cmtOpen{{deal_id}}");
    console.log(cmb);
    cmb.on("click", function(event) {
     console.log('comment modal opened');
     commentClick();
    });
    
  $(".btn btn-custom btn-xs").ready(function() {
    console.log('Submit is ready')
    var smb = $("#cmtSubmit");
    console.log(smb);
    smb.on("click", function(event) {
     console.log('Click on Submit Button');
     newComment();
    });
    });  
   });
 });
};

  var searchFilter = function() {
   var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, select;
   input = document.getElementById("searchBar");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   table = document.getElementById("renewals");
   tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   col = $("#colFilter option:selected").val();
   
   for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
     td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[col];
     if (td) {
       if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr[i].style.display = "";
       } else {
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
     }
   }
  };
  
  var commentClick = function() {
      var commentId = $(this).data("id");
      $("#txtId").val(commentId);
      console.log(commentId);
    };
  
  var newComment = function() {
    var sendCmt = $("#cmtSubmit")
    sendCmt.on("click", function() {
      var body = $(this).val("#commentBody");
      console.log(body);
      /*var deal_Id = $(this).attr("data-deal-id");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.azuqua.com/flo/8f2907de23ab6b0c987afeea9e25b0a7/invoke?clientToken=21efb4ba9c3d7d36e951c2af850b0fcf56cd606913c98ef342f104da1eab6bce",
        data: {"comment":body,
               "deal_Id":deal_Id
              },
        statusCode: {
          200: function(){
            window.location.reload(true);
          };
        };
      });*/
    });
  };
```

The problem I am trying to solve (without adding a modal window into EACH line in the table) is how do I associate data from a column in the row where the comment button was pressed with the payload I am going to send via an .ajax() POST call (the commented out portion of the code). Part of that issue is also getting the JS to understand WHICH comment button I am pressing, and I think from there I should be able to figure the rest out.

I am pretty new to JS and HTML, so please let me know of any errors or bad practices you see, I still learning! I wasn't quite sure what would be needed so I just included everything.

thank you DevWorld for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id in every row to uniquely identify it, and work some jQuery magic from there.

Comment: That is what I tried to do with the id of the 'Comment' button in the HTML where it says ```id="cmtOpen{{deal_id}}"``` but the issue is getting the JS to recognize what button I am pressing